# python 3, tkinter NonType error

Tags: tkinter, nonetype, pack

I have read numerous posts about people with `NonType` errors because they have tried to `.pack()`, `.grid()` or `.place()` on the same line as defining the `tk widget` variable.

**Example**

```
execute = tk.Button(text="Start", command=lambda:
Elements.ClickApp()).place(x=20, y=250, height=20, width=50)
```

Responses have been that it's **A**, not possible with 2 functions, and **B** difficult to read in one line anyway. I started out (reluctantly) accepting an additional line for `.pack()`, `.grid()` or `.place()` but have now encountered additional lines (which don't even work). Such as:

```
T = tk.Entry()
T.bind("<Key>", Elements.Tbox)
T.place(x=20, y=230, height=20, width=50)
```

Not only can these three lines not be placed in one line, which is what I want .. but the code does not even function. Instead the first button pressed is ignored, then the second button (and onwards) triggers `Elements.Tbox`.

Instead, newlines must be increased further:

```
sv = tk.StringVar()
sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=sv: Elements.Tbox(sv))
T = tk.Entry(textvariable=sv)
T.place(x=20, y=230, height=20, width=50)
```

Which then correctly triggers `Elements.Tbox` on the first button press.

Is there a way, (maybe with `lambda`) these new lines can be reduced? ... When dealing with large groups of widgets, it reads easier to group widget this way. I find this more readable then separate lines.

**UPDATE**

I have included sample code with the **answer** to this question ... although the answer marked correct is probably better advice. This is incase someone out there needs to do this or something similar, you can do the following:

**Entry Widget Example:**

Combining `EntryBox = tk.Entry()` with `.place()`, `.pack()` or `.grid()`

```
(lambda g: [(EntryBox.place(x=0, y=0, height=20, width=190)) for g['EntryBox'] in [tk.Entry()]])(globals())
```

Comment: You can always use `;` to enter multiple expressions in a single line, just like in C, but I doubt that's a good way.

Comment: Is the bind issue related? Is this question anything but merging multiple lines of python code into one?

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried ... its was a last resort consideration ... its not ideal ... it also doesn't work when configuring a listbox / scrollbar combination which links to each other in the '.config' of each.

Comment: The bind issue is an example stumbled upon of further need to increase new lines ...  it does involve reducing lines

Comment: I don't think you should reduce the lines below what they are. The bind issue is unrelated and it implies an error on the coding side. If you have multiple widgets try to use collection types and loops.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You start by asking one question, then switch to asking something different, and eventually end up with something completely different. Please consider rewriting your question to ask one single thing, with code that accurately reproduces your problem.

Comment: I will consider re-writing it ... however it is very clear ... I would like to shorten the first example of code ... If it is not possible, I would like to shorten the second example of code (and have it work) ... If that is not possible, I would like to shorten the third example of code.

Comment: You can remove "T=" in 3rd example and put Entry and place on one line because you can use/get a StringVar and don't use the reference to the Entry anywhere else.  If you have a large group of widgets, use a for or a function to create them instead of each one individually.

Comment: I will look into this. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you worried about the number of lines of code when the command in your buttons are not functioning? I failed to find a question in your rant, and voted to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to reduce these three lines to something which has fewer lines:

```
T = tk.Entry()
T.bind("<Key>", Elements.Tbox)
T.place(x=20, y=230, height=20, width=50)
```

The short answer is, you can't. At least, not without making the code harder to understand which is an anti-pattern for software development.

The reason is just a fundamental aspect of programming in a dynamic language like python: you can't refer to objects before they exist. Thus, a widget must exist before you can call `pack`, `place`, `grid`, or `bind` on it. And given that those functions return `None`, you can't chain them like you might be able to in other languages.

You may be tempted to combine the first and third statements like this:

```
T = tk.Entry().place(x=20, y=230, height=20, width=50)
```

That won't work either. The reason is that `T` will be set to `None`, making it impossible to refer to the widget later. This is because in python, `x().y()` returns the value of `y()`, thus with `Entry().grid()`, `grid` always returns `None.

In my experience you should never group your widget creation and widget layout commands together. Instead, create your widgets in one group, and lay them out in another. The same is usually true for bindings as well.

Why? Because usually when you're needing to solve a layout problem it involves changing the options for more than one widget, so it's convenient that they are grouped together.

In my experience, GUI code is easier to read and manage when it code that does similar things is grouped together, rather than grouping all statements related to a the same object.

For example:

```
x = tk.Entry(...)
y = tk.Button(...)
z = tk.Label(...)

x.grid(...)
y.grid(...)
z.grid(...)

x.bind(...)
y.bind(...)
z.bind(...)
```

This isn't a hard and fast rule, of course. The goal should always be clarity, and there are times when it makes sense to put the widget creation and layout together, though that's usually if you are dealing with just a single widget.

If you are wanting to create a bunch of identical widgets where the arguments are nearly identical, instead of cramming as much as possible on a single line you should create a helper function.

For example, in your case you might want to make a create_entry function:

```
def create_entry(master, x, y, width, height, callback):
    entry = tk.Entry(master)
    entry.bind("<Key>", callback)
    entry.place(x=x, y=y, height=20, width=20)
    return entry
```

With that, you now have your coveted one-line solution:

```
T = create_entry(root, 20, 230, 20, 50, Elements.Tbox)
U = create_entry(root, 20, 290, 20, 50, Elements.Tbox)
V = create_entry(root, 20, 290, 20, 50, Elements.Tbox)
...
```

Comment: is it possible to combine `T = tk.Entry()` with `pack()`, `grid()` or `place()` into one line using a `lambda`? I'm trying to see if its possible to 'initialized' each widget in one line.

Comment: @Rhys: you can put it on  line line, but then you lose the ability to refer to the widget later because `x().grid()` returns the result of `grid()`, and `grid`, `pack`, and `place` all return `Null`. Like I wrote in my answer, in my experience it's best to keep them separate. It will make your code easier to debug and easier to modify over time.

Comment: Mm ok, I'll mark your answer correct. The reason I ask this is question is ... I had written a large Qt4 program and revisited it 2 years later. I had initialized the widgets similarly to your **2nd example** ... but found it grew increasingly confusing, like a 'wild goose chase'. So with tkinter, I've been trying to prevent this potential problem from the beginning. My example 3 shows how, even starting out the code has begun to increase in complexity during the init stage